# changing ViewChild implementation to support multiple, generic components

Tags: angular, viewchild

I currently have a webpage with a componentcontainer:

HTML:

```
  <ng-container #componentContainer></ng-container>
```

Typescript:

```
@ViewChild('componentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) componentContainer: ViewContainerRef;
```

The component is inserted via the following function:

```
private createComponent(pageItem: PageItem, 
    factory: ComponentFactory<BaseTemplate>, isMultiPage: boolean): void {
    const compRef = factory.create(this.injector);
    if (compRef !== null) {  
        // Set some variables on the items
        compRef.instance.PageComponent = pageItem;
        compRef.instance.MultiPageItemPage = isMultiPage;

        // Important to watch for changes.
        compRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); 
       this.componentContainer.insert(compRef.hostView);
       this.CurrentDynamicComponents.push(

     TemplateComponentLoaderService
         .createDynamicComponentModelForPageItem(pageItem, 
             compRef)
       );
    }
}
```

I wish to refactor this to work for a list of generic components.

I changed my HTML to:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of Page.Rows" >
    <div *ngFor="let col of row.Columns" class="row">
        <div [ngClass]="{ 'col-md-1': col.Width == 1,
                          'col-md-2': col.Width == 2,
                          'col-md-3': col.Width == 3,
                          'col-md-4': col.Width == 4,
                          'col-md-6': col.Width == 6,
                          'col-md-12': col.Width == 12 }" test=test>

            <ng-container *ngFor="let com of col.Components" #componentContainer>

            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This works so far, but obviously I do not have unique Ids for my componentContainer. Im not sure how to go about solving this problem. Does anyone have any advice on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want an index of iterated components. So you can use `index` of `ngFor`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let com of col.Components; let i = index" #componentContainer>
    <!-- here you can use i as an index to your component -->    
</ng-container>
```

UPDATE:

There is no way to style `<ng-container/>` because `<ng-container/>` is not inserted in HTML, however, we can style your component like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let com of col.Components; let i = index" #componentContainer>
    <com [ngStyle]="{'font-size': fontSize+'px'}"></com>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: The componentContainer will have different widths en css, so I want to create different containers like #componentContainer-1, #componentContainer-2, etc. But I am not sure how I can  use and populate an array of ViewContainerRef  and how I can match the ViewContainerRefs with the corresponding DOM element in ts code